# A pyenv related error occurs in the zsh terminal of MacBook Air M1

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, apple-m1

An error occurs whenever I turn on the terminal.

```
# Terminal

/Users/{username}/.zshrc:103: command not found: pyenv
/Users/{username}/.zshrc:104: command not found: pyenv
```

```
# line 103, 104 of /Users/{username}/.zshrc 

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

There's no problem with the annotation. But I think I wrote it down because I needed two codes when I used Catalina, so is it okay if I don't have it?

Oh, but using `brew install pyenv` caused an installation error.

It was installed using `arch -arm64 brew install pyenv` as the guide in the error message.

Not only pyenv, but also pyenv-virtualenv.

The Catalina time machine was moved to the new MacBook Air M1, and the data seemed to have passed normally, but none of the applications have passed.

What's the problem? Did the other people have their applications transferred together?

Ah, the existing workspace folder, the GitHub clone folder, has all disappeared.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You need `pyenv`, but it wasn't transferred from the old machine to the new machine. So install it.

Comment: @chepner
I'm sorry if you didn't understand the question. I understood that i have to install it again. so i installed it. But every time I turn on the terminal, there is an error related to pyenv. How do we deal with this?

Comment: Where did you install it? You may need to update your `PATH` as well.

Comment: How to set up your new laptop isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow. apple.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I transferred to Anaconda and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it ended up being The line, `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` was above the homebrew eval line, `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)` in my `.zshrc`.